# Bootstrap 5 navbar-light and font-style not working on Edge

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, microsoft-edge, bootstrap-5

I am having an issue with my website on microsoft edge. It works fine on chrome, but when I try to load the page on edge navbar "navbar-light" and "bg-light" classes doesn't seems to work and the page font style is default. I am using bootstrap5 and webfonts for the font. How can I solve this?

This is the index.html page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--<link href="assets/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <title>bootstrap</title>

</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand-md">
        <div class="container">
            
           <!-- pro botao hamburg aparecer na esquerda, igual no rede market, eh so botar ele antes da logo-->
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/Rio-Turismo.png" width="90px"
                 alt="Rio Turismo"></a>
           
                 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#menu" 
                 aria-controls="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Botão de navegação">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>

           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
              <div class="navbar-nav me-auto">
                 <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#passeios">Passeios</a>
                 <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#excursoes">Excursões</a>
                 <a class="nav-item nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">Passeios Culturais</a>
                

                 <div class="dropdown-menu">
                     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Museus</a>
                     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Feiras</a>
                     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Bibliotecas</a>
                     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Livrarias</a>
                 </div>
  
                 <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Reservas</a>
                 <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#header">Contato</a>
              </div>

              <div class="d-none d-sm-block">telas small pra cima</div>
              <!--div q n eh mostrada em mobile-->

              <div class="navbar-nav">
                 <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#pedidos">Meus Pedidos</a>
                 <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#janelamodal">Entrar</a>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </nav>

    <img src="images/panoramica1.jpg">

    <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Add some CSS so that we can see ourselves what the issue is.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Are the js and css files you imported in the page correct?

I did a simple test using the code you provided, and it shows the same effect in Chrome Version `95.0.4638.54`  and Edge Version `95.0.1020.30`.
The three resource files are:

```
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

And the result:
[image]

If possible, could you provide more details that we can reproduce this issue? This will help solve the problem, thank you for your understanding.